# How to serialize data into a DTO in C#?

Tags: c#, json, rest, pojo, dto

This is my first day working with C# and I have a question regarding making requests and creating DTOs. In Java, I can serialize object structures that resemble the expected response. An example of this is,

```
public class SignInRS extends BaseEntityRS {

    @SerializedName("data")
    public Data data;

    public class Data {

        @SerializedName("user")
        public User user;

        @SerializedName("session")
        public Session session;

    }

}
```

The question I have is, can I do the same for C#? For example,

```
public class SigninRS : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Data data;

    public class Data
    {
        public User user { get; set; }
        public Session session { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string id;

        public string phone;

        public string email;
    }

    public class Session
    {
        public int expirationMinutes;

        public string utcExpirationTime;

        public string pteExpirationTime;
    }
}
```

My concern is that I cannot use annotations in C#. I have tried, and I receive errors. How can I accomplish making RESTful APIs?

Comment: Start by searching the Serializable attribute.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Thanks for the tip. In Java, we do not have attributes. That keyword may help me find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at any Json serializer implementation. The most popular in .NET world is [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). In your case you can simply do something like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
```

Comment: Ok, I think this may work for me. Seems simple enough. I will accept answer shortly. Thanks!